# Call log in symbian

Tags: symbian

I am a beginner to Symbian. I have to work on the application in which I can get the data on the incoming, outgoing, answered, unanswered and missed calls.
The data like number, name (if the number exists in phonebook of the mobile), time, duration.

Which api I have to use to make this possible?

Comment: This can be closed under the official reason: _Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google is your friend. Its always worth a search.
Nokia Symbian call log example: http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/320b0a08-3c5b-4c27-961b-058a97d6d3b9/S60_Platform_Log_Example_v1_0.zip.html

Comment: Thanks i had already tried to download it from there but i got the corrupted file always